# Facebook registration plugin giving error

Tags: php, facebook, json, plugins, registration

I am using the following iframe json code to bring up a form on my website for user registration. Though when i add custom fields after a certain number of those, i get an error which says:

**Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
Referer
/n**

I tried contacting my hosting help , they said that there is an issue with the facebook code, But i guess thats not what the problem is because upto certain number of check boxes the code works fine but as soon as it goes beyond that , i get the above error. Here's the Code :

```
            <iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
                                    client_id=325340244194060&
                                         redirect_uri=http://www.pingcampus.com/facebook_registration_plugin/fbwe/trial.php&
                                    fields=[
            {
                "name": "name"
            },
            {
                "name": "email"
            },
            {
                "name": "gender"
            },
            {
                "name": "birthday"
            },

            {
                            "name": "Arts",
                            "description": "Arts",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Arts"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Act",
                            "description": "Act",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Act"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Cooking",
                            "description": "Cooking",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Cooking"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Dance",
                            "description": "Dance",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Dance"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Designing",
                            "description": "Designing",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Designing"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Fashion",
                            "description": "Fashion Designing",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Fashion Designing"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Interior",
                            "description": "Interior Designing",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Interior Designing"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Modeling",
                            "description": "Modeling",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Modeling"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Photography",
                            "description": "Photography",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Photography"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Poetry",
                            "description": "Poetry / Writing",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Poetry / Writing"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Programming",
                            "description": "Programming",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Programming"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Reading",
                            "description": "Reading",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Reading"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Sketching",
                            "description": "Sketching / Drawing",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Sketching / Drawing"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Singing",
                            "description": "Singing",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Singing"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Sports",
                            "description": "Sports",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Sports"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Stunting",
                            "description": "Stunting",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Stunting"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Videography",
                            "description": "Videography",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Videography"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Other",
                            "description": "Other",
                            "type": "checkbox",
                            "value": "Other"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "captcha"
                        }


            ]'
                                    scrolling="auto"
                                    frameborder="no"
                                    style="border:none"
                                    allowTransparency="true"
                                    width="500"
                                    height="800"

                     >
                            </iframe>
```

Can anyone guess where am i going wrong? I am processing the form by php using the example code given [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/). If needed Please ask for the code i will provide the php code as well but its almost the same as the example on the above link

Answer (score 0):

A "get" request often has a limit. So when you return to your server, the resulting get request exceeds that limit. (limit is set by Apache config). Nothing to do with Facebook, that limit is set by your hosting provider, so you were right to ask them.

Options:

1. Ask hosting provider to increase limit (unlikely)
2. Store the data in a session variable, or in a database table connected to a unique id. On return, get data from the session, or use the unique id as the parameter sent to Facebook, and use that unique id in return to establish the full data.this method also had other advantages (reveals less data, allows less manipulation by the end user)

Comment: So if i directly connect to database on the same page which is receiving these variable and store the variables in some table , will resolve the issue ? 

Is this what you are trying to say?  @Robbie

Comment: I'm actually saying you need to shorten your return URL. Sorting the details in a database and connecting to that database is one method. You need to store the variables and associate it with a unique id (primary key, butt make it hard to guess by using uniqueid and not a simple number). Then use that unique is to retrieve the values after connecting to Facebook. (or use sessions)